# Automating GUI based application written in Java on windows

Tags: java, windows, winapi, automation, winappdriver

I am trying to understand and use winappdriver for recording and playing GUI based app testing in windows. I have a few questions:

(1) Is the windows default spy/inspect tool which gives ID of GUI component capable of giving ID of any GUI written in Java. I mean when using swing library etc, we don't give ID to a component like button,text area etc then how will the inspect tool know any ID.

(2) The winappdriver comes with a recorder UIRecorder. Can we use this to get ID of java based GUI app and have these IDs played automatically to simulate record and play requirement of my RPA.

Comment: It's very possible it works on your Java application as it's independent on the language, framework etc. but it's possible it doesn't work either. For the inspect tool, just try it on the application. It will be much easier than wild guessing.

Comment: @SimonMourier : Yes, downloaded a simple Java GUI based calculator from internet and tried. Inspect tools don't give automation id.

Comment: You can automate an application without automation ids, many Windows app don't exhibit ids. What's important is to have all elements hierarchy.

Comment: @SimonMourier : Could you please help with how to automate using elements hierarchy..

Comment: Just google for UI Automation or here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-ui-automation